# How do the specific code on a specific page or URL

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two questions about CodeIgniter code ( or just ideas )

1. I want the code to do the specific code on a specific page or URL.
2. How to get the title of specific URL.

I am new in the  CodeIgniter coding, I want some ideas!

Comment: see `route` , `controller`, `method` to know about all.

Comment: You can add some code that you have created, so that some people will understand more about your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create route in "/application/config/routes.php". You have an exemple here with and without parameters :

```
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/view/$1';
$route['posts'] = 'posts/index';
```

You can take a look on the routing documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

posts/view/$1 and posts/index is the controller_name/action called by the route.

If you have other question, just comment.

Have a nice day !